# A one-liner to place some number of Graphics3D polytopes on a plane and to randomly assign colorations

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I'm looking for a nice one- or two-liner to randomly place some number, $N$, of `Graphics3D` polytopes on a plane with dimensions $X \times Y$, and to specify that $k \leq N$ of them should be one color (e.g. `Red`) and the remaining $N-k$ another color (e.g.  `Blue`).  If possible, I would also like the option to randomly reassign colors an arbitrary number of times (perhaps by clicking a mouse) without changing the coordinates of the polytopes.  Is this possible?

We can get started by placing a single red colored `Dodecahedron` at the coordinate $(0,0,0)$ with the following line of code:

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Scale[Translate[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"], {0, 0, 0}], 3]},
          Boxed -> False, Background -> Gray]
```

Perhaps we would want to use `Map` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a bit long for a comment, but maybe this will get you started:

```
Graphics3D[
  Array[{If[# < 5, Red, Blue], 
  Scale[Translate[
  PolyhedronData[RandomChoice[PolyhedronData[]], "Faces"], 
    {RandomInteger[{-25, 25}], RandomInteger[{-25, 25}], 0}], 3]} &, 
    RandomInteger[{5, 10}]], Boxed -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {{-30, 30}, {-30, 30}, All}]
```

I will leave it to you to scale the numbers to your liking.

(and I couldn't find a nice solution for the mouse-clicking question)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly compact:

```
Module[{n = 20, k = 5, pd, polys, col},
 pd = N @ PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"];
 polys = Translate[pd, {##, 0}] & @@@ RandomReal[{-20, 20}, {n, 2}];
 col = Table[Red, {k}] ~Join~ Table[Blue, {n - k}];
 EventHandler[Graphics3D @ Dynamic @ Riffle[col, polys],
  {"MouseClicked" :> (col = RandomSample @ col)}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Far from a one-liner, I'm afraid:

```
number = 20;
positions = 
  Table[{RandomReal[{-20, 20}], RandomReal[{-20, 20}], 0}, {number}];
colorfunction[n_, k_] := If[n >= k, Red, Blue];
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
  Table[{
    colorfunction[c, k], 
    Scale[
     Translate[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"], 
      positions[[c]]], 3]
    }, {c, 1, number}]],
 {k, 1, number}]
```

[image: random polytopes]

Notice that they overlap! Luckily you didn't specify that they couldn't... :)

Random colors:

```
number = 20;
positions = 
  Table[{RandomReal[{-20, 20}], RandomReal[{-20, 20}], 0}, {number}];
colorfunction[n_, k_, col1_, col2_] := If[n >= k, col1, col2];
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Button["random",
    {colour1 = RGBColor [RandomReal[1, 3]],
     colour2 = RGBColor [RandomReal[1, 3]]}],
   Graphics3D[
    Table[{
      colorfunction[c, k, colour1, colour2], 
      Scale[
       Translate[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"], 
        positions[[c]]], 3]
      }, {c, 1, number}],
    ImageSize -> {400, 400},
    PlotRange -> {{-30, 30}, {-30, 30}, All}]}],
 {{k, number/ 2}, 1, number},
 Initialization -> {colour1 = Red, colour2 = Blue}]
```

[image: colored random polytopes]

Comment: Very nice answer!  Just as a note, for the random colors I meant "randomly assign the red coloration, for example, to $k$ of the objects" and "randomly assign the blue coloration to $N-k$ of the objects".  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

A variation on Simon's method using `ClickPane`:

```
Module[{n = 20, k = 5, pd, polys, col}, 
 pd = N@PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"];
 col = Table[Red, {k}]~Join~Table[Blue, {n - k}];
 polys = Translate[pd, {##, 0}] & @@@ RandomReal[{-20, 20}, {n, 2}];
 Dynamic @ ClickPane[Graphics3D @ Riffle[col, polys], (col = RandomSample @ col) &]]
```

[image]